# Cox Proportional Hazards Interaction Hazard Ratios

Tags: interaction, cox-model, hazard

I am looking at the interaction of dose (continuous with mean=2241 and sd=949.4) and cause of death (values of 0 or 1) in a survival analysis. The interaction is tending towards significance, and since this is a small sample, I was hoping to dive a little deeper. How do I interpret this interaction Also, is there more I should look at to explore this interaction? Appreciate all the help.

UPADATE: after adjusting the unit change for Dose to 100, the hazard ratios are 1.044 and 0.984.

```
proc phreg data=data; 
CLASS COD; 
MODEL SURVIVALTIME*EVENT(1) = COD|DOSE; HAZARDRATIO DOSE; HAZARDRATIO COD; where COD in (0,1); 
RUN;
```

[image]

Comment: What units are your `Dose` values in? What's a typical value for `Dose`? Hazard ratios are reported for a 1-unit change in a continuous predictor ("Dose Unit=1"), so if your `Dose` values are in the hundreds to thousands then those could represent potentially large hazards in practice. Please edit your question to add that information, as comments are easily overlooked and can be deleted.

Comment: Good call of the unit change issue. After adjusting the unit change for Dose to 100, the hazard ratios are 1.044 and 0.984.